# Why RavenDB reads all documents in indexing process and not only collections used by index?

Tags: ravendb

I have quite large database with ~2.6 million documents where I have two collections each 1.2 million and rest are small collections (<1000 documents). When I create new index for small collection, it takes lot of time indexing to complete (so temp indexes are useless). It seems that RavenDB indexing process reads each document in DB and checks if it should be added to index. I think it would perform better to index only collections used by index.

Also when using Smuggler to export data and I want to export only one small collection, it reads all documents and exporting might take quite a lot of time. Same time custom app which uses RavenDB Linq API and indexes can export data in seconds.

Why RavenDB behaves like this? And maybe there is some configuration setting which might change this behavior?

Comment: I wish Raven team would add an optional list of "Collection" to index definition. If that list is empty, then index process work as is. However, if that list is defined then only collections from that list should be considered by index. It would improve performance dramatically and should be very simple to implement. 

We have similar issues with Smuggler. Our own implementation is using Raven-Entity-Name but with a collection filtering and is significantly faster than Smuggler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that answer to my question is coming in RavenDB 3.0. Ayende says:

> In RavenDB 2.x, you still have to pay the full price for indexing
> everything, but that isn’t the case in RavenDB 3.0. What we have done
> is to effectively optimize the process so that in this case, we will
> preload all of the documents taking part in the relevant collection,
> and send them directly to be indexed.
>
> We do this by utilizing the Raven/DocumentsByEntityName index. Which
> has already indexed everything in the database anyway. This is a nice
> little feature, because it allows us to really take advantage of the
> work we already did long ago. Using one index to pre-populate another
> is a neat trick, and one that I am very happy about.

And here is full blog post: http://ayende.com/blog/165923/shiny-features-in-the-depth-new-index-optimization

Answer (score 3):

RavenDB doesn't actually have any real concept of a "collection".  All documents are pretty much the same.  It simply looks at the `Raven-Entity-Name` metadata in each document to determine how to group things together for purposes of querying by type and displaying the "Collections" page in the management studio.

I am not sure of the specific rationale for this.  I think it has something to do with the underlying ESENT tables used by the document store.  Perhaps Ayende can answer better.  Your particular use cases are good examples for why it might be done differently.

One thing you could try is to use multiple databases.  You could put the your large-quantity documents in one database, and put everything else in another.  Of course, you may have problems with indexing related documents, multi-map/reduce, or other scenarios where documents of different types need to be together on the same database.